# What is the difference between Precipitable Water (PW or PWAT) and Quantitive Precipitation Forecast (QPF) in terms of computer weather model data?

Tags: meteorology, models, water, precipitation

When I take a look at weather models, there is an option to take a look at PWAT or QPF. What's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

[**Precipitable water**](http://en.mimi.hu/meteorology/precipitable_water.html) is the total amount of moisture throughout the air (the total in the entire tropospheric air "column"; most moisture is found in the lowest few km, due to decreases in temperature and density and where humidity sources being at the ground).

Whereas [**QPF**](http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Quantitative_precipitation_forecast) is the amount of precipitation that has fallen or is predicted to fall in a certain period of time (often 6 or 24 hours).

Generally more moisture (higher PWATs) do indicate the potential for more precipitation.  But you could definitely have a large PWAT and get no rain/snow/etc to fall from the sky.

I believe the greatest PWAT values are typically found in the warm saturated columns near tropical cyclones (hurricanes/typhoons).  From experience, in the US South, PWATs near/above 2 inches are generally considered quite large in the summer, and tend to indicate a greater chance of rain from air mass/sea breeze/frontal storms.

Whereas hourly rainfall rates can often be nearer 3-5 inches per hour, and locations can report over 20 inches of rain in a day [[rainfall records]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_weather_records#Rain).